# HowTo: customize & internationalize error codes/messages in Symfony?

Tags: error-handling, internationalization, validation, symfony-1.4

Is there a simple way to modify/customize error messages generated by Symfony validators?

eg. When using a string validator, if the field is empty, 
then the message "Required" is displayed by default with the field.

This surely comes from its class, but is there a way to change the message for the String Validator globally so that it applies to all instances?

Thanks in advance.

PS: wouldn't appreciate a solution that requires changes to the Symfony base code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose there is auto-translation for such messages. Just place the message in your translation file and symfony will render it based on the selected locale

Answer (score -1):

I yet don't know if you can manipulate the default error messages globally, but you can access the i18n Object where you want with these lines of code:

```
$i18n = sfContext::getInstance()->getI18N();
$i18n->__('your message');
```

Maybe it helps you.

Comment: Hi, this Q is about modifying error messages generated by form validators. thanks